# NgRx : dispatch one event from a store to another

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm beginning to use @ngrx and I'm facing an issue to which I can't seem to find an answer.

I illustrated it in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkwps7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) : when a player picks a race, the specialty should be set back to undefined.

At first I thought I could use the reducer, but it doesn't have knowledge of the store without injection.

How should I approach this issue ?
*(Note : this is a reproductible example, I know I can put a second dispatch in my functions. What I want is to do it automatically)*

Related code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, Action, ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 
`
<select #race (change)="dispatchRace(race.value)" placeholder="Select a race">
  <option value="Elf">Elf</option>  
  <option value="Orc">Orc</option>  
  <option value="Dwarf">Dwarf</option>
</select>

  <select #spec (change)="dispatchSpecialty(spec.value)" placeholder="Select a specialty">
  <option value="Warrior">Warrior</option>  
  <option value="Berzerkrer">Berzerkrer</option>  
  <option value="Healer">Healer</option>  
</select>

<p>
  Current race: {{ (currentRace | async) || 'None' }}
</p>
<p>
  Current Spec: {{ (currentSpecialty | async) || 'None' }}  
</p>  
`
})
export class AppComponent {

  currentRace = this.store.select('race');
  currentSpecialty = this.store.select('specialty');

  constructor(public store: Store<CharacterState>) { }

  dispatchRace(race) {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetRaceAction(race));
  }

  dispatchSpecialty(spec) {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetSpecialtyAction(spec));
  }
}


const SET_RACE = '[RACE] Set';
const SET_SPECIALTY = '[CLASS] Set';

export class SetRaceAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_RACE;
  constructor(public race: string) { }
}

export class SetSpecialtyAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_SPECIALTY;
  constructor(public specialty: string) { }
}

export function raceReducer(state: string = undefined, action: SetRaceAction): string {
  return action.race || state;
}

export function specialtyReducer(state: string = undefined, action: SetSpecialtyAction): string {
  return action.specialty || state;
}

export interface CharacterState {
  readonly race: string;
  readonly specialty: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a `console.log` in the `raceReducer` you can see that all the actions are handled by all the reducers :

```
export function raceReducer(state: string = undefined, action: SetRaceAction): string {
  console.log(action);
  return action.race || state;
}
```

You just need to handle `SetRaceAction` and `SetSpecialtyAction` differently.

[Edit of the stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52498684)

Comment: The console log simply displays the action. I know what's in the action, what I want is to use `store.dispatch(new SetSpecialtyAction(undefined))` when I dispatch a race action.

Comment: You want to dispatch an action from the reducer ?

Comment: If that's how it's done, then yes, but I don't know how it's done. I looked up effects and selectors rapidly to see if it could be used, but I didn't find an answer in either of them.

Comment: Did you take a look at the edit I suggested ? Does it have the desired behavior ?

Comment: Your edit doesn't set the specialty back when the race is selected ... **EDIT** Oh it does the opposite, wait a second, I'm looking at it

Comment: Ow ok I fixed it. I was selecting race when speciality is selected xD.

Comment: It indeed works, thank you ! will lazy loading create an issue on that ? I currently import my stores in related modules, so they could not have access to actions from another stores ?

Comment: Never faced issues with lazy loading and handling actions in multiple reducers.

Comment: Your answer resolves my issue, but I'm realizing my case is more complicated than what I initially said. I'm making another question for it, but thank you anyway !

Answer (score 3):

So if I understand correctly: you want to dispatch one action that triggers another?

1. **this is best done using NGRX effects**. Your effects file will listen for the action, and dispatch both when the action is caught. (excuse the snippet, i was having formatting issues)

```js
// make sure to import rxjs 6 correctly
import { map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Effect()
twoActionEvent = this.actions$
    .ofType(appActions.FIRST_ACTION)
    .pipe(
        switchMap((action$: appActions.firstAction) => {
            return //what ever you need in the first action
        }),
        map((firstActionPayload) => {
            return {
               type: appActions.FIRST_ACTION_SUCCESS,
                payload: firstActionPayload
            }
         }),
         tap(() => {
             this.store.dispatch(new appActions.SecondAction(//payload))
         })
     );
constructor(private actions$: Actions,
            private store: Store<AppState>) {}
```

2. another way to do this would be to listen for the action in your app, by subscribing to a property in your store, and when that property is true: dispatch the second action

Comment: I'm going to test that and get back to you, thank you !

Comment: I have an issue with your switchMap signature, I'm supposed to return an observable, and you return a plain object ?

Comment: I do not, that is example code. it answers the question but I will not do the work for you. if you return a plain object you  need to wrap it in an observable. Using the 'of' operator. If you don't, you could just use map instead of switchmap. But you need to handle the implementation of your specific case yourself.

Comment: Following your logic, I could simply do a `subscribe` and chug it all in it. What I meant was that I don't understand effects, and I thought you had to return an action or something (I instantly thought of `return new SetRaceAction(action.race)`, to picture it). Generic code isn't very answering my question, I've seen tutorials online explaining effects. Since I provided a [mcve], I thought I could have an example fitted to it ...

Comment: stack overflow has never been a place for people to have guaranteed code they can copy and paste in, the minimal example is great, the question is confusing as you have asked a couple things, I gave you my best attempt at an answer, and it includes an example, but stack o guidelines do not require fully functional specific answers to the OP's q. It gave you a way to handle multiple actions, apparently by your accepted answer you actually just needed a reducer. just goes to show, the question wasn't totally clear, I'm happy to give my time to help out on here, but I won't write your code.

Comment: I asked one thing, and I gave an example to illustrate it, with a sandbox to show how to proceed ... While I agree we're not code monkeys, I made a perfectly valid question following [ask] guidelines, and not a `Need to dispatch two events from store, please help` typeof question. And the accepted answer doesn't resolve my issue, apparently only effects can. So I'm going to dig into it and hope to find a solution, but as for your answer, it is indeed of poor quality. I'm not downvoting because you did help me by pointing the right feature, and I thank you for that !

Comment: I'm really not trying to pick a fight man. If the answer accepted doesn't work, I don't know why you excepted it. Hopefully mine helps, good luck. My answer is a perfectly good example of how to write a 2 action effect, though it does not delve into how to wrap objects in observables etc. as that wasn't the question.

Comment: I didn't implement the right thing in the example, but the guy did answer to it, so with other people facing the same issue in mind, I marked it as resolved. I don't want to pick a fight either, just giving my two cents like you did ! And your answer did help, so thank you for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add one more solution, that I have done in my own implementations when I use flags in my store.

just change the flag in your state during the action you dispatch, for example:

```
import * as AppActions from './app.actions'; import * as handler from './app.models';

export function appReducer(
        state: handler.AppState = handler.initialAppState,
        action: AppActions.AppActions
    ) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case AppActions.SET_RACE_ACTION:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    race: action.payload
                    // set your flag in state
                    myFlag: undefined
                 }
       }
```

}