# Ngrx effects : output not getting added to the actions stream

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

The problem can be reoduced in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhbg7v?file=src%2Fapp%2Feffects.service.ts).

The example is simple : the user chooses a race and and a specialty.

I want that when the race is chosen, the specialty is reset(ed ?).

To do that, I created an effect :

```
@Effect()
raceChange = this.actions
  .pipe(
    ofType(SET_RACE),
    mapTo(new SetSpecialtyAction(''))
  );
```

But the action is not being added to the stream. Could someone explain me why ? (I'm new to @ngrx, so please be thorough !)

PS : I know I can use [the solution from my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498684/ngrx-dispatch-one-event-from-a-store-to-another/52499028), but I'm trying to learn ngrx basics.

code for stackblitz component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, Action, ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 
`
<select #race (change)="dispatchRace(race.value)" placeholder="Select a race">
  <option value="Elf">Elf</option>  
  <option value="Orc">Orc</option>  
  <option value="Dwarf">Dwarf</option>
</select>

  <select #spec (change)="dispatchSpecialty(spec.value)" placeholder="Select a specialty">
  <option value="Warrior">Warrior</option>  
  <option value="Berzerkrer">Berzerkrer</option>  
  <option value="Healer">Healer</option>  
</select>

<p>
  Current race: {{ (currentRace | async) || 'None' }}
</p>
<p>
  Current Spec: {{ (currentSpecialty | async) || 'None' }}  
</p>  
`
})
export class AppComponent {

  currentRace = this.raceStore.select('race');
  currentSpecialty = this.specStore.select('specialty');

  constructor(
    public raceStore: Store<RaceState>,
    public specStore: Store<SpecialtyState>,
    ) {
      this.currentRace.subscribe(x => console.log('race : ', x));
      this.currentSpecialty.subscribe(x => console.log('spec : ', x))
    }

  dispatchRace(race) {
    this.raceStore.dispatch(new SetRaceAction(race));
  }

  dispatchSpecialty(spec) {
    this.specStore.dispatch(new SetSpecialtyAction(spec));
  }
}


export const SET_RACE = '[RACE] Set';
export const SET_SPECIALTY = '[CLASS] Set';

export class SetRaceAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_RACE;
  constructor(public race: string) { }
}

export class SetSpecialtyAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_SPECIALTY;
  constructor(public specialty: string) { }
}

export function raceReducer(state: string = undefined, action: SetRaceAction): string {
  return action.race || state;
}

export function specialtyReducer(state: string = undefined, action: SetSpecialtyAction): string {
  return action.specialty || state;
}

export interface RaceState {
  readonly race: string;
}

export interface SpecialtyState {
  readonly specialty: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mapTo` maps the emission to a string, using `map` would map to an action which would be dispatched.

To make your example work I changed two things :

1- replace the `mapTo` by `map` in the effect :

```
@Effect()
raceChange = this.actions
   .pipe(
     ofType(SET_RACE),
     map(() => new SetSpecialtyAction(''))
);
```

2- Change the reducer that was ignoring empty values :

```
export function specialtyReducer(state: string = undefined, action: SetSpecialtyAction): string {
  return action.specialty;
}
```

```js
const value = '' || 'Not Empty';
console.log(value);
```

[Here is a working fork.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52516610)

You can also map to multiple actions using `switchMap` and returning an array fo actions :

```
@Effect()
raceChange = this.actions
   .pipe(
     ofType(SET_RACE),
     switchMap(() => [new SetSpecialtyAction(''), ...])
);
```

Comment: Damn me, I totally forgot I was ignoring empty values ! This alone resolved my issue. I'm taking into account your remarks about `mapTo` and `switchMap` too, thank you ! Quick question if you know how : given I have two actions, how could I emit a `SetRaceAction` in my effect without triggering an infinite loop ? Do I have to create a new state for that ?

Comment: Technically, you could have a filter in the effects `RxJs` pipe to prevent the infinite loop. But I would avoid effects that could trigger each others.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an effect, you can listen to the race action inside the speciality reducer:

```
export function specialtyReducer(state: string = undefined, action: SetSpecialtyAction | SetRaceAction): string {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_RACE:
      return '';
    default:
     return action.specialty || state;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've said I am already using, and I don't want to use because I'm learning effects.

Comment: I want to defend my answer a bit here because you didn't say this and you aren't using the solution I wrote here. If you want to learn effects you should also know when to use effects and when you shouldn't. This case doesn't really "do" a side effect and simply changes state, thus makes it a fit to use  reducers. Also the accepted answer might introduce troubles later on when you introduce more actions, because the reducer will always clear the state when there is no `specialty` provided on the action.

Comment: This is a [mcve], not a real world case. I'm trying to see how effects work and what they do. Thanks to the accepted answer, I do now. I implicitly said I was using this solution, which is linked in my question, that you apparently didn't read at all. Your answer is good, don't get me wrong, I have nothing against it : my issue is that you completely ignored the context of the question and basically created a duplicate. This question was about effects not working (because I did something stupid), and not about what is the best solution to use there.

Comment: :thumbsup: I must have understood your question wrong.